# Range of transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Today I learnt the concept of *linear transformation* and this was the first excercise I found regarding the range of a linear transformation:

> Find the range of the linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ specified as

> \begin{equation*}
>         f(x, y, z) = \Big(x - y + z, x + y + 2z, 2x + 3y -5z, 2x - y +z,  4x + 3y -z \Big)\end{equation*}

I would appreciate some validation on whether my procedure is correct, since I'm so new to the subject. I will mostly skip calculations, since I'm interested in the validity of the general procedure. What I did is described below.

---

Let $\textbf{x} = (x, y, z)$. Consider all vectors $f(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^5$ satisfying

\begin{align*}
    \textbf{y} = \begin{cases}
       y_1 &= x - y + z \\
       y_2 &= x + y +2z \\
       y_3 &= 2x + 3y - 5z \\
       y_4 &= 2x - y + z \\
       y_5 &= 4x +3y - z
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Clearing for $x, y, z$ one boils the system to

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{cases}
        y_2 &= 12y_1 - \frac{17}{2}y_4 + \frac{3}{2}y_5 \\
        y_3 &= -18y_1 + 12y_4 - y_5
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

so that any $f(\textbf{x})$ is of the form

\begin{align*}
    f(\textbf{x}) &= \Big(y_1, 12y_1 - \frac{17}{2}y_4 + \frac{3}{2}y_5, -18y_1 + 12y_4 - y_5, y_4, y_5 \Big) \\
    &= y_1\Big(1, 12, -18, 0, 0 \Big) + y_4 \Big(0, -\frac{17}{2}, 12, 1, 0  \Big) + y_5\Big(0, \frac{3}{2}, -1, 0, 1\Big)
\end{align*}

In other words, the range of $f$ is the span

\begin{align*}
    \text{Im}(f) = \Big\{ \lambda_1\Big(1, 12, -18, 0, 0 \Big) + \lambda_2 \Big(0, -\frac{17}{2}, 12, 1, 0  \Big) + \lambda_3\Big(0, \frac{3}{2}, -1, 0, 1\Big) \mid \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R} \Big\}
\end{align*}

The vectors whose linear combination is described above are linearly independent and form a basis of $\text{Im}(f)$. As expected from the fact that the kernel has dimension $0$ (proof omited), the range of $f$ is three-dimensional as is its domain.

---

Is this procedure correct? If so, was there a simpler way to find the range of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. Not only the procedure; I've checked the answer and it is correct.

However, there is a simpler approach. Since $f(1,0,0)=(1,1,2,2,4)$, $f(0,1,0)=(-1,1,3,-1,3)$, and $f(0,0,1)=(1,2,-5,1,-1)$,$$\operatorname{Im}(f)=\left\{\lambda_1(1,1,2,2,4)+\lambda_2(-1,1,3,-1,3)+\lambda_3(1,2,-5,1,-1)\mid\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context on why we are sure $\text{Im}(f)$ is such space? As I understand it, you are evaluating $f$ at each basis $b_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. But I can't see why from that follows the range of $f$ is $\{\lambda_1f(b_1) + ... + \lambda_3f(b_3)\}$.

Comment: If $v\in\Bbb R^5$, then\begin{align}v\in\operatorname{Im}(f)&\iff v=f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\text{ for some }\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\Bbb R\\&\iff v=\lambda_1f(1,0,0)+\lambda_2f(0,1,0)+\lambda_3f(0,0,1)\text{ for some }\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\Bbb R,\end{align}since$$f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=\lambda_1f(1,0,0)+\lambda_2f(0,1,0)+\lambda_3f(0,0,1).$$

Comment: Very clear! Here, $\{ \lambda_if(b_i) + ... + \lambda_3f(b_3)\}$ spans $\text{Im}(f)$ but is not necessarily a basis of $\text{Im}(f)$, correct? If $\text{Im}(f)$ had dimension $m < 3$ then $f(b_1), ..., f(b_3)$ would necessarily be linearly dependent. Am I correct in infering this?

Comment: Thank you very much by the way!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm glad I could help.